# how to join or merge as one row in SQL

Tags: sql

I have these 2 tables;

table A

```
| ID | Name   | S_ID |
|----|--------|------|
| 1  |  mark  |  1   |
| 2  |  john  |  2   |
```

table B (rows are not limited to 5 and Scores could be more than 3)

```
| ID | S_ID | Score |
|-------------------|
| 1  |  1   |  90%  |
| 2  |  1   |  80%  |
| 3  |  1   |  10%  |
| 4  |  2   |  10%  |
| 5  |  2   |  12%  |
```

Normally using "GROUP_CONCAT" would work but is there any way to achieve this;

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You are asking for a pivot query, either with or without a fixed number of columns.  Assuming the former, we can use `ROW_NUMBER` here:

```sql
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY S_ID ORDER BY ID) rn
    FROM tableB
)

SELECT
    a.ID,
    a.Name,
    MAX(CASE WHEN rn = 1 THEN b.S_ID END)  AS S_ID_1,
    MAX(CASE WHEN rn = 1 THEN b.Score END) AS Score_1,
    MAX(CASE WHEN rn = 2 THEN b.S_ID END)  AS S_ID_2,
    MAX(CASE WHEN rn = 2 THEN b.Score END) AS Score_2,
    MAX(CASE WHEN rn = 3 THEN b.S_ID END)  AS S_ID_3,
    MAX(CASE WHEN rn = 3 THEN b.Score END) AS Score_3
FROM cte
GROUP BY
    a.ID,
    a.Name;
```